# Why WindowsIdentity class is not visible in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Having the code below in VisualStudio 2017 .NET Core 2.0 Console App

```
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace smallTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting the error:

```
The name 'WindowsIdentity' does not exist in the current context
```

If I can see this class in .NET Core 2.0 library in [.Net Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity?view=netcore-2.0) ?

Same code works in .NET Console app.

**[EDIT]**

**@Will @JohnnyL** Commented that I do not refer, `System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll`, that is true.

But I am curious why it is not working, because
in .NET 4.6.1 project (where class WindowsIdentity is visible) I also do not refer this `System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll` specifically. However i refer System.dll.

I always thought that it works like namespace hierarchy. For instance, when I refer to

`System.Security.Principal.dll`

i can use class which is in

`System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll`.

Am I wrong?

I added `System.Security.Principal.dll` to .NetCore solution by hand but it still does not work.

**[EDIT2]**

**@Will** Thank you a lot for expaining the subject it helped me a lot. 
I tried to figure out is WindowsIdentity compatible with Core and it seems that it is please see:

in this [apisof.net](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity) in Declarations area i can see that WindowsIdentity is in `.Net Core 2.0   System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=4.1.1.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`
but i do not have `System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll` in references, should I add it? If yes from where?

in [.NET Core api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-2.0&term=WindowsIdentity) i see this class in the list (what is the purpose of that listing if it is not compatible with core?

I also find information about that class in [that link](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Principal.Windows/System/Security/Principal/WindowsIdentity.cs,200d683bfb324fda)

Am I looking in wrong places?

Comment: WAG, but you're probably not referencing System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll.

Comment: There's a string `Assembly:` in docs with assembly where this class lives

Comment: @Will  and JohnyL Thank you for the tip, please see my edit.

Comment: 4.6.1 isn't Core. IIRC in the full framework WindowsIdentity lives in mscorlib (checked, it does). Core doesn't reference the same assemblies as the full framework.  Types are defined in assemblies.  If type A is in assembly Foo.dll, you have to reference Foo.dll to use A.  You need to check the docs for the framework you are designing against (in your case, .net core) and check to see in which assembly a given type is defined. This information is also sometimes included in the quick actions and refactorings lightbulb...

Comment: @Will I added Edit2

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Microsoft announced Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core a few weeks ago,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/

And by analyzing the source code of `System.Security.Principal.Windows.csproj` and the commit adding it,

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Principal.Windows/src/System.Security.Principal.Windows.csproj

My conclusion is that this is also part of the Windows only compatibility libraries, so can only be used on Windows.

To add that to your project, open your csproj and add a `PackageReference` tag for `System.Security.Principal.Windows` manually (or use Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager).

Comment: "If you’re building Windows desktop applications, then the .NET Framework is the best choice for you".

Comment: @LexLi Thank you very much for explaining the subject in such detail. So the browser on page [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-2.0) is indeed showing classes and assemblies which are compatible with .Net Core.

Comment: @Reven, yes. .NET API Browser matches the GitHub code base. The ["Applied to"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity?view=netcore-2.0#Applies_to) section shows .NET Core is supported, but to locate which NuGet package to include, you need to scroll back to the top and read "Assemblies" section. It is far from intuitive but no better alternative right now.

Comment: For further reference: if rebuilding doesn't help, try restarting VS.