# How to use System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, windows-identity, .net-core-2.1

How can we use `WindowsIdentity` in .NET Core 2.1?

It was available in 2.0

**.NET API Browser**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=WindowsIdentity&view=netcore-2.0
  `WindowsIdentity` is available
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=WindowsIdentity&view=netcore-2.1
  `WindowsIdentity` is not available

Comment: "It was available in 2.0", so what happened to it? Check which packages you have installed and what was updated. Maybe you inadvertently uninstalled it? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Principal.Windows/

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I didn't inadvertently uninstalled it, but it seems like MS removed it from .NET Core 2.1 and put it into a nuget package.

Comment: The NuGet package exists since 2014, it's not even close to a new one... That said, I cannot find anything stating they removed it from .NET Core itself: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.1/api-diff/2.0-vs-2.1.md

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes that was my question/confusion. .NET API Browser does not show it anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the update... I would suggest you to open a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues. Not a lot we can do here unfortunately

Comment: Can you not reference it from the dll? should be in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll` (windows install)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why WindowsIdentity class is not visible in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776680/why-windowsidentity-class-is-not-visible-in-net-core)

Answer (score -3):

You can find the current Windows username using: `System.Environment.UserName`.